# Why is it enough to push OFFSET of variable to Win32 API using MASM?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly

> Why is it enough to push OFFSET of variable to Win32 API using MASM?

I've read the docs about `OFFSET`, where it is said that this operator returns the offset of the expression into the relevant segment.

However, when using the `MessageBox` function I push arguments like this:

```
push OFFSET title
```

But if the `.data` segment is located at memory address `x` and title is located at address `x + 16`, then `OFFSET title` is equivalent to `16`?

However, how can the `MessageBox` function use such a value? I mean the value doesn't imply the ASCII string stored at label `title`?

-Thanks

Comment: No, `offset title` is not 16, it's the actual address of the `title`. The naming comes from `segment:offset` but in flat memory model segment base is 0, so all you have is the offset. (Except for special segments `FS`/`GS`). Note that `.data` and friends should better be called a section, not a segment, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you @Jester. Just to be sure...: The .data, .code, etc. are all sections located within the same segment? Each segment in a flat memory model starts at memory address 0? Are there more than one segment? If so, how does push knows which segment it should locate the data?

Comment: Yes, `CS`,`DS`,`ES`,`SS` all have base 0 and they share the same memory space.

Comment: Are the .data and .code segment in the same segment then? How does the OFFSET operator know which segment to compute offset into?

Comment: Yes, all of those are the same. The offset is relative to the segment not the section.

Comment: The segments were important (and complicating things) in 16b mode (there calling BIOS with offset assumes, that your `ds` belongs to the provided offset), or if some OS doesn't use flat memory mapping (don't know if any). I don't know about OS inner workings, but I would expect current OS to create completely virtual memory map for your app context, with segments being 0, and addresses of sections being randomized (to make it harder for exploits to inject and execute custom code trough some bug in app) hiding the true physical memory addresses (each other app/process has different virtual map)

Comment: It is because of the 32 in Win32.  32-bit code uses a flat address space.  Just a single address, segments play no role anymore.

Comment: @Ped7g: ASLR is only possible for position-independent code.  OS X requires PIC executables, but Windows and Linux only require PIC for shared/dynamic libraries.  Windows/Linux executables can contain code that uses absolute addresses, rather than relative, so randomizing the virtual address where code was loaded would cause it to break.

Comment: @ped7g: You can't see physical addresses because of paging, and you can't do anything with them either.  That's not interesting...

Comment: Windows actually does not require PIC for libraries, either. The OS loader fixes up all addresses automatically. DLLs are just PE files (like executables), and all PE files are relocatable. This problem was solved way back in the 16-bit days (or perhaps even the 8-bit days). Microsoft's compiler/linker do not even support generating PIC, as far as I know.